# Mode Rewrite 301 Redirects

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Our website has a new URL structure and we require some pages to be redirected 301 using mod rewrite.

Old URLS

www.example.com/en/car-parts/159-black-toyota-convertable.html

New URLS

www.example.com/cars-parts/black-toyota-convertable.html

As you can see from the above the new URL removes:

/en/
/159-

The en is the language and the 159- is the ID of the product these both need to be removed.

I have tried the below but with no joy.

```
RewriteRule ^en/([0-9]+)-([^/.]+)/?$ /$1
```

The above gives me the result:

/159

Any one got any ideas please?

Thanks

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your rule $1 is the result of the capture of the subparttern `([0-9]+)`, not `([^/.]+)`, which is $2.

```
RewriteRule ^en/\d+-([^/.]+)/?$ /$1 [L,R=permanent]
```

For this simple task, we can also use `RedirectMatch`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, I have tried your suggestion but it doesnt work, also when I change $1 to $2 it still gives me /159

Comment: It cannot, have you clear your cache? According to your example, these rules never match because 1) the part `car-parts` is not handled 2) idem for the dot in extension. The rule should be more something like this: `RewriteRule ^en/([^/]+)/\d+-([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$2 [L,R=permanent]`

Comment: Yes your right I did miss out the /car-parts/ I am running the rules in a Mod ReWrite tester: http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ still no joy with it.

Comment: This tool does not recognize PCRE features like \d: replace \d with [0-9].

Comment: Julp - Thanks I will test on dev site then, cheers for you help.